# StringBuilder.Append puts text in the new line in case of long string C#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

As you can see below i want to append some texts in the same line,but when one portion is to an extend long,its located in the new line and it turn out to two line string.

```
        using (var wr = new StreamWriter(filepath,true))
        {
            var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            strBuilder.Append(UtilityBillId);
            strBuilder.Append("|B|");
            strBuilder.Append(billId);
            strBuilder.Append("|B|");
            strBuilder.Append(paymentId);
            strBuilder.Append("|B|");
            strBuilder.Append(stepTitle);
            strBuilder.Append("|B|");
            strBuilder.Append(resultCode);
            strBuilder.Append("|B|");
            strBuilder.Append(resultMessage);
            strBuilder.Append("|B|");
            strBuilder.Append(Common._getCurrentDateTime());


            wr.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());
        }
```

when the `resultMessage` is  long some part of it located in new line

good to mention that when i use `File.ReadAllLines(path)` it shows same result in the text file.

you can take a look at the result text through link below

[Result](http://%20https://gofile.io/?c=zKwkbF)

Comment: Check if `resultMessage` contains no `\n` characters

Comment: maybe it shows like that in the editor? Try to copy the value and paste it to the text editor with wrap option off.

Comment: no it does not.

Comment: File.ReadAllLines(path) shows the same result.

Comment: Upload the generated file to pastebin etc so someone else can look at it? I'm 99% sure it'll be that your editor is wrapping the line.

Comment: The code above doesn't add any explict newline to your stringbuilder. So we are left with two options: A) the newline is present in one of the variables used above. B) The tool used to look at the result simply wraps the text because it is too long to show in the current output window (or tooltip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will produce a file with only one line:

```
        Regex r = new Regex("[\r\n]");
        var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.Append(UtilityBillId);
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.Append(billId);
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.Append(paymentId);
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.Append(r.Replace(stepTitle, ""));
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.Append(resultCode);
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.Append(r.Replace(resultMessage, ""));
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.AppendLine(Common._getCurrentDateTime());

        File.AppendAllText(filepath, strBuilder.ToString());
```

I assumed anything ending in ID was an int, and I also assume the datetime doesn't have a newline in it

Test it and see if it also "produces a file with two lines" - if it does, i'm 100% sure it's your editor wrapping the line.

Answer (score 2):

String builder has nothing to do with new lines unless there is a `\n` or you append manually a a `System.getProperty("line.separator")`. The only thing that changes with the length of the string is the memory allocation.

Here you have a part of documentation explaining it:

The StringBuilder.Length property indicates the number of characters the StringBuilder object currently contains. If you add characters to the StringBuilder object, its length increases until it equals the size of the StringBuilder.Capacity property, which defines the number of characters that the object can contain. If the number of added characters causes the length of the StringBuilder object to exceed its current capacity, new memory is allocated, the value of the Capacity property is doubled, new characters are added to the StringBuilder object, and its Length property is adjusted. Additional memory for the StringBuilder object is allocated dynamically until it reaches the value defined by the StringBuilder.MaxCapacity property. When the maximum capacity is reached, no further memory can be allocated for the StringBuilder object, and trying to add characters or expand it beyond its maximum capacity throws either an ArgumentOutOfRangeException or an OutOfMemoryException exception.

For more info you can check the official microsoft thread:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8

In case that any of your strings contain a `\n`, your problem is that the tool you use for visualizing the text is wrapping it on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Based on 'Caius Jard' answer i changed my code and it solved my issue.

```
        Regex r = new Regex("[\r\n]");
        var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.Append(UtilityBillId);
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.Append(billId);
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.Append(paymentId);
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.Append(r.Replace(stepTitle, ""));
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.Append(resultCode);
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.Append(r.Replace(resultMessage, ""));
        strBuilder.Append("|B|");
        strBuilder.AppendLine(Common._getCurrentDateTime());

        wr.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());
```